# react redux-saga where to handle some logic

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using redux-saga with React. Lets say i'm fetching some data from server that need some external client side calculation. My question is where to put them.
my saga looks something like this:

```js
function* someEffect(action){
    try{
        //removed none related stuff from the code.
        const data = yield call(someRequestFucntionThatUsesAxios, requestparams);
        if(data.status>=200&&data.status<300){
            yield put({type:SUCCESS, payload:data.data)};
        }
    catch(err){
    }
}
```

In the above code `data.data` needs some calculation(basic math mostly). Now, which one of these options makes more sense?
handling those calculations in my connected components `componentDidUpdate` method.
handling them right after receiving it (before dispatching to to reducer).
(I know that reducer is no place for such behaviour but since it doesn't kill to ask,) handling it inside my reducer.

Comment: Use `transformResponse` in axios

Comment: another approach would be doing calculation inside `mapStateToProps` and pass the result as prop of the component. Using `selectors` with `reselect` might be overkill but good for large scale apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said `reducer` is not the best place to modify the API response, neither saga is.

I would suggest you to use `transformResponse` function in axios, to modify the response just right after it is returned from API.

```
axios.get('/', {
   transformResponse: (data) => { 
      // do whatever you like with the data
   },
});
```

Comment: I was not aware of such func. Thanks for the reply. I will check it out

Comment: what would you suggest the calculation should live if they are done on multiple on click events?